# Unknown name SBNotificationHub in IOS azure mobile services in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, cocoapods

after reading the article of [Mobile Azure Services Getting Started](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/#) and implement the **SDK** using [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AzureSDK-iOS#changelog) i stuck with an error that said

> Unknown type SBNotificationHub

here is the full code that I already have

**AppDelegate.m**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  TestRemotePush
//
//  Created by Zakaria Darwish on 8/21/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Zakaria Darwish. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <WindowsAzureMobileServices/WindowsAzureMobileServices.h>
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                            UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *) deviceToken {
    SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] 
// here is the error mentioned //

initWithConnectionString:@"<Enter your listen connection string>"
                                                             notificationHubPath:@"<Enter your hub name>"];

    [hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:nil completion:^(NSError* error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
        }
        else {
            [self MessageBox:@"Registration Status" message:@"Registered"];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)MessageBox:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)messageText
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:messageText delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

For more Details about how I implement the Mobile Azure Services is using the terminal pod install after creating a Podfile inside my project and navigate to it using the terminal and then initiate the comment pod install